# Having trouble with apache shiro saltedauthentication.hashProvidedCredentials not given expected hash

Tags: java, spring, security, shiro, saltedhash

This is the second time I'm using `apache shiro` in a project but the first time am `salting` the password.this time around i use `apache shiro 1.2.0` . I'm using shiro in a web application using jsp, spring, JPA(spring-data-jpa) and using `SHA256` for encryption then `base64` before saving to database. I have a `SaltedJPARealm`, a `Sha256CredentialMatcher` which implements a HashedCredentialMatcher. this is how i do

**creating a user in my controller**

```
RandomNumberGenerator rng = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
ByteSource salt = rng.nextBytes(10);              
        String hashedPasswordBase64 = new Sha256Hash(signupForm.getPassword(),salt).toBase64();

userService.createUser(signupForm.getFullName(), signupForm.getEmail(), hashedPasswordBase64, salt.toBase64());
```

so supposed my password is `password1234` and the generated salt is `/ZFfGOcSxYhy+g==` so in my database i have password: `whb+0AihIGJ4n8QwULj1tR6qSwCrA+1BUvnoe4q4Cy4=` the salt in the `salt field in the database` is the same.

In my configuration in spring is:

```
<!--....-->
 <bean id="saltedJPARealm" class="bla.bla.webapp.security.SaltedJPARealm">
    <constructor-arg  ref="credMatcher"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="credMatcher" class="bla.bla.webapp.security.Sha256CredentialMatcher">
        <property name="storedCredentialsHexEncoded" value="false" />
        <property name="hashAlgorithmName" value="SHA-256" />
        <!--<property name="hashIterations" value="1024" />-->
    </bean>
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager" depends-on="userRepository">
    <property name="realm" ref="saltedJPARealm" />
</bean>
<!--....-->
```

**login user**

```
 Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
 if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(loginForm.getEmail(), loginForm.getPassword(), loginForm.isRememberMe());
  SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(token);
        }
```

The `SaltedJPARealm's doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken at)` returns `SaltedAuthenticationInfo` after getting the user from the database :

```
ByteSource salt = ByteSource.Util.bytes(user.getSalt());           
return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user, user.getPassword().toCharArray(),salt,this.getName());
```

the `doCredentialsMatch` of Sha256CredentialMatcher looks like :

```
    Object tokenfromSubmition = hashProvidedCredentials(token.getCredentials(),((SaltedAuthenticationInfo)info).getCredentialsSalt(),0);
    Object passwordFromStorage =this.getCredentials(info);

    Boolean match = equals(tokenfromSubmition, passwordFromStorage);
    return match;
```

full code is available [here on pastie](http://pastie.org/5061920) the authentication fails with this. but when i change the code not to salt the password(when creating account) and return AuthenticationInfo as opposed to SaltedAuthenticationInfo. it works with the same class. am wondering what exactly am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the PasswordMatcher and PasswordService?  These automatically use securely randomly generated salts and perform password comparison directly.

Comment: the `passwordService` use per default `sha-256` encryption and 50,000 iteration (i think so) and i haven't found any way of changing these default values.when tried it seems to be slow during debugging when generating the password. so i fall back to custom implementation. thanks

Comment: I answered your question about `passwordService` usage below.  I know it doesn't address your originally posted question, but I think you'll find it much easier/nicer to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PasswordService` is a POJO (with nested properties) and its nested properties can be configured just as well with Spring:

```
<bean id="passwordService" class="org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService">
  <property name="hashService.hashAlgorithmName" value="SHA-512"/>
  <property name="hashService.hashIterations" value="500000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myRealm" class="...">
  <property name="credentialsMatcher">
    <bean class="org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher">
      <property name="passwordService" ref="passwordService"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

This allows the `myRealm` instance to use the PasswordService for credentials *checking* during a login attempt.

To use the PasswordService to encrypt passwords when the end user *sets* their password (i.e. during account registration or password reset), you can inject the `PasswordService` bean and then use it:

```
String encryptedPassword = passwordService.encryptPassword(signupForm.getPassword());

userService.createUser(signupForm.getFullName(), signupForm.getEmail(), encryptedPassword);
```

I think you'll find the Spring config and code usage much nicer/cleaner to use than the lower-level random number generators and HashService + Hash APIs.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your response. with your suggestion is the Realm the same? :
`protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken at) 
      //.....
           return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(user, user.getPassword().toCharArray(),this.getName());
           }`

Comment: @blacksensei P.S. This approach assumes you use the PasswordService to set the password in your data store first (as shown above in the 2nd code block).  Then the stored value can be used to do a comparison during login.

Comment: How do you get the PasswordService to begin with? Is that owned by the SecurityManager somehow?

Comment: @JessBowers as shown in the code example above, it is just instantiated manually (`<bean id="passwordService" ...`).  Then you inject the `passwordService` bean into your application code *and* the CredentialsMatcher instance, so both components reflect the same object.